# Plotting a map until the user hits contrl-c Python

Tags: python, tweepy, matplotlib-basemap

Hi guys I am trying to draw a bunch of plots on a map and my program is continually plotting these points on the map, but I am wanting it to where it'll draw up the map when the user hits control-c to stop the program. Any idea why this is not drawing up the map when I hit control-c? In theory when the user hits control-c the interrupt keyboard exception will prompt the plt.show()

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import json
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import csv

ckey = '
csecret = '
atoken = '
asecret = '

m = Basemap(projection='mill', llcrnrlat=20, urcrnrlat=50,\
        llcrnrlon=-130, urcrnrlon=-60, resolution ='c')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawstates()
m.fillcontinents(color='#04BAE3', lake_color='#FFFFFF')
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#FFFFFF')

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):

         try:
            if status.coordinates:

                #print status.text
                print status.coordinates
                #print 'place:', status.place.full_name
                coords  = status.coordinates
                latitude = coords['coordinates'][0]
                longitude = coords['coordinates'][1]
                x,y = m(latitude, longitude)
                m.plot(x,y,'ro', markersize=20, alpha=.5)
                print latitude
                print longitude

            return True
         except KeyboardInterrupt, e:

            plt.show()
            sys.exit()
       #     time.sleep(5)



    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["justin", "bieber"])
```

Answer (score 0):

This would only work while `on_status()` is executing. Any Ctrl-C entered outside of that will not call `plt.show()`. Try moving the `try...except` outside of `listener`.

```
try:
    auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
    auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
    twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
    twitterStream.filter(track=["justin", "bieber"])
except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
    plt.show()
    sys.exit()
```